# ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41) Unhandled Exception: Connection reset by peer

Tags: android

I use Flutter Google map to develop a app and i got the below errors:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrZ1D.png)

here is my AndroidManifest.xml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfpAX.png)

This is my request:

```
class MapServices {
  final String key = 'AIzaSyCcvInqXroc8BNmikambBXZRMlYw2pvXL0';
  final String types = 'geocode';

  Future<List<AutoCompleteResult>> searchPlaces(String searchInput) async {
    final String url =
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=$searchInput&types=$types&key=$key';

    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    var json = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);

    var results = json['predictions'] as List;

    return results.map((e) => AutoCompleteResult.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getPlace(String? input) async {
    final String url =
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=$input&key=$key';

    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    var json = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);

    var results = json['result'] as Map<String, dynamic>;

    return results;
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getDirections(
      String origin, String destination) async {
    final String url =
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=$origin&destination=$destination&key=$key';

    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    var json = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);

    var results = {
      'bounds_ne': json['routes'][0]['bounds']['northeast'],
      'bounds_sw': json['routes'][0]['bounds']['southwest'],
      'start_location': json['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['start_location'],
      'end_location': json['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['end_location'],
      'polyline': json['routes'][0]['overview_polyline']['points'],
      'polyline_decoded': PolylinePoints()
          .decodePolyline(json['routes'][0]['overview_polyline']['points'])
    };

    return results;
  }

  Future<dynamic> getPlaceDetails(LatLng coords, int radius) async {
    var lat = coords.latitude;
    var lng = coords.longitude;

    final String url =
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?&location=$lat,$lng&radius=$radius&key=$key';

    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    var json = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);

    return json;
  }

  Future<dynamic> getMorePlaceDetails(String token) async {
    final String url =
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?&pagetoken=$token&key=$key';

    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    var json = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);

    return json;
  }
}
```

Please help me !! Thanks god....

I have checked my Google Maps Platform project settings. But i cannot find any useful information.